# using a C# list as datasource of datagridview (Winform)

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

the question says it all , i want to use a list as a datasource and i wrote the code below :

```
var uname = DB.TBL_USAGE.Where(x => x.UName != null).ToList();

        List<usage> lst = new List<usage>();

        foreach (var item in DB.TBL_USAGE)
        {
            lst.Add(new usage { uname = item.UName, bytesout = item.Bytesout });
        }

        var bndngsrc = new BindingSource();
        bndngsrc.DataSource = lst;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bndngsrc;
```

and this is the class :

```
    public class usage
    {
        public string uname;
        public string bytesout;
    }
```

but no luck !

can any one present a code that works or correct my code ?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or WinForms?

Comment: @Steve its a winform project

Comment: I would try with _BindingList<usage> bs = new BindingList<usage>(lst); dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;_ although your code seems to be correct

Comment: By the way, you make a sublist excluding items with uname==null but then you loop over the whole table. This doesn't make sense, have you posted redacted code?

Comment: @Steve i believe i have tested binding list too , it just gives me a column whith `lenght` and some numbers (i think string lenghts), i used uname!=null to go through all records in the table.

Comment: So, something else is happening here. That code should work. Perhaps you could show more of your code. Did you check if the TBL_USAGE is empty? How do you call this code? How do you create the form that contains the DataGridView?

Comment: @Steve yes,the table contains data and i set a breakpoint on the foreach code the `lst` is filled with th `TBL_USAGE` data, i have also checked with a list box and could get the `uname` and `bytesout` as items (string) on the listbox,its just the damn Grid that wont show the data.im getting hopeless !

Comment: As explained before this code should work. If not then it is not related to the code you have shown here. I repeat my questions above. How do you call this code? Please show the code flow that ends in the code above and should show your grid filled with data.

Comment: @Steve i was testing the code above and its on a test form,i call the code from a button

Answer (score 0):

```
   var uname = DB.TBL_USAGE.Where(x => x.UName != null).ToList();

    List<usage> lst = new List<usage>();

    foreach (var item in DB.TBL_USAGE)
    {
        lst.Add(new usage { uname = item.UName, bytesout = item.Bytesout });
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = lst ;
```

\

Comment: How do you know if this is an ASP.NET project?

Comment: @Steve its a winform project

Comment: Then DataBind doesn't exist for a DataGridView control. This answer is wrong

Comment: @MohsenK, just assign the lst to DataSource. No need to DataBind

Comment: Then delete this answer